# mantis time out issue

Tags: php, mantis

I have configured Mantis, the thing is after sometime if I stay idle, Mantis sort of timeout. I refresh the page again and again but it does not load Mantis at all. Whenever I restart XAMPP it starts working fine (until I don't sit idle).

Here are some settings that i have seen w.r.t exipration

```
# token expirations
define( 'TOKEN_EXPIRY', 60 * 60 );

# Default expiration of 60 minutes ( 3600 seconds )
define( 'TOKEN_EXPIRY_LAST_VISITED', 24 * 60 * 60 );
define( 'TOKEN_EXPIRY_AUTHENTICATED', 5 * 60 );
define( 'TOKEN_EXPIRY_COLLAPSE', 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
```

Can someone tell me how to get through this timeout thing whatever it is? I am using "Mantis 1.2.8".

Comment: please check [this](http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3953),it might help

Comment: actually i have already tried it thx by the way but still there is some other issue.

Comment: thats actually what i am trying to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what u need to do. On authentication_api.php you must comment this part like this

```
$t_login_methods = Array(
    MD5,
//      CRYPT,
    PLAIN,
);
```

and it will work found that from mantis forums.

Answer (score 0):

The offical way is to change you configuration file (config_inc.php).

Make sure you have a line in config file like `$g_reauthentication_expiry = 60*60*2;` This is for example 2 hours for admin to need re-login.